# как открыть дисковод с помощью python на Windows? (на компьютере и ноутбуке)

Tags: python, windows, диск

как написать скрипт на python который сможет открыть дисковод?

Comment: Не знаю, пробовали ли вы искать самостоятельно, но в гугле находятся как минимум несколько примеров кода на гитхабе :) Если пробовали и не получилось, то думаю, что лучше было бы указать в вопросе такой код.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3177896/5909792

Answer (score 5):

Для `Linux`, `NetBSD`

```
import os
os.system("eject cdrom")
```

Для `windows`

```
import ctypes
ctypes.windll.WINMM.mciSendStringW(u"set cdaudio door open", None, 0, None)
```

Comment: скрипт запустился без ошибок, но изменений нет, то есть дисковод не открылся. 
Использую ноутбук c дисководом (DELL), Windows 7

Comment: Попробуйте ctypes.windll.WINMM.mciSendStringW(u"set cdaudio door open", None, 0, None)

Comment: помогло, большое спасибо)

Comment: Интересно то, что код из комментария не отличается от ответа.

Comment: @AndroID Посмотрите изсторию редактирования ответа

Comment: @Вадим Александру Извините, но как? P.S.: Мобильный.

Comment: открыть получилось, а как его закрыть?

Comment: @Акмаль я думаю это уже отдельный вопрос

Comment: может надо просто вместо open написать close? просто у меня ноутбук, поэтому я не могу это проверить